# Formula to check a condition

Tags: excel

Please find the condition below:

```
Col A   Col B  Col C   Col D
235     A      B        Formula result
235     B
235     C 
236     X
236     Y
236     Z
237     P
240     Q
```

I need a formula in col D to check that if Col A is 235 then Col C should have any value from A,B or C mentioned in the list in col B. if Col A is 236 then col D should give me an error if values are not between X,Y or Z.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Enter this formula in D1: `=IF(A1=235,IF(C1=B1,"Okay!","Error"),IF(OR(C1="X",C1="Y",C1="Z"),"Okay!","Error"))`

Comment: This is not working as I need to check if from a list mentioned in col A, I should get any value mentioned corresponding to that value in col B.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is very unclear (that's why it got closed!). Better provide same example results in your list, so one can see what you really need. Also, look at the elements of the formula I provided - pretty sure that these elements (`OR`, `IF`) are all you need for your task!

Comment: This is not working as I need to check if col C is 235, then Col D should have any value between A,B or C (which are mentioned against the list specified). I should be able to validate whether it is meeting this condition or not. APologies for not making it clear.

Comment: Look, if you want people to help you, it'd be much better if you phrase the question in an understandable way - and not simply so "but your solution doesn't work!"! Else, good luck in finding somehow willing to help you...